# How can Recognize handwriting number

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

Which algorithms should use to recognize handwriting numbers from an image? 
Can write this algorithms in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read books about image processing algorithms.
There some useful book in Internet.

Such as : computer vision algorithm.